# After fetching the document on AWS Kendra using langchain output contains Document as type, is there a way to reformat that in python dict

Tags: langchain, amazon-kendra

it has structure like this:
'source_documents': [Document(page_content = 'user data',
metadata = {})]

Comment: what you want to achieve? you should not modify it if you are using langchain after this retrieval, it has dependencies and your chain will keep on failing with errors. if you want to convert it into dict and use it for custom purpose then you can convert it the way you want.